# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Mathematica breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  1         12
Users destroyed                                  18          0
Users contacted                                   4          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            25        791
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               23        675
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         30        927
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                9        206
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               160      2,812
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              354      6,141
Tags merged                                      31          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            19          0
Tag synonyms created                             19          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               59         35
Questions protected                               3          8
Questions migrated                               61         33
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0        226
Questions closed                              1,006      1,784
Question flags handled⁴                          91        135
Posts unlocked                                    0         62
Posts undeleted                                   9        322
Posts locked                                      1        138
Posts deleted⁵                                  338      3,275
Posts bumped                                      0      1,215
Comments undeleted                                9          0
Comments flagged                                  0        134
Comments deleted⁶                             1,468      4,779
Comment flags handled                           107         27
Answers flagged                                   3        720
Answer flags handled                            519        204
All comments on a post moved to chat             35          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Does "Questions closed by moderators" include situations where the 5th close vote was cast by a moderator?

Comment: @Szabolcs My guess is yes (based on number of questions closed during last quarter by all mods, ~270)

Comment: I was asking because I noticed that the number of questions closed by moderators is higher than on some other sites I looked at. However, our moderators will frequently wait until there are 4 close votes already, which means that they are effectively not using moderator powers when closing.